# Why is my GIS Shapefile (CRS 4326) not viewed from directly above?

Tags: r, gis, netlogo, shapefile, map-projections

I have loaded two shapefiles into Netlogo. One shapefile's original projection was 4326 (osmdata) and one was originally 28992 (Dutch government data) which was st_transformed(4326) in R. When I load them into Netlogo, it does not display the shapefile directly from above, which it does do from R ggplot

[image: projection in NETLOGO]

[image: projection in R ggplot]

Why is this and how do I get it viewed from above?

Comment: When you say it's not viewed from above, do you mean that it has been compressed vertically (in the y dimension) in the Netlogo World? Without seeing the file / how you've loaded it, this is just a guess, but it *looks* like the projection is either not being loaded into NetLogo *or* that the `gis:set-transformation` / `gis:set-world-envelope` have not been set quite right.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by using `gis:set-world-envelope-ds` instead of `gis:set-world-envelope`